# Ideal k value in kNN for classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, knn

I am doing a classification (not clustering). Can I use kNN algorithm for this? What is the ideal k value to test? In some stackflow answers I saw that they have adviced to use the square root of the number of features. But from where this rules comes from? Can someone please help me :)

Comment: @NominSim I found ' the square root of the number of features' from your answer :) so please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general notion, **k** is chosen to be **sqrt(n)**,where **n** is the number of data-points,not the features. 
But the only way to validate your model is by the error on test data.

What I generally do is, choose few random data-point from the dataset,and then find the **k** nearest neighbours for them.Count the number of neighbors with the different classes from the selected point.If the number of neighbors with different classes is too high,then change the value of **k**.

Comment: I am using 10 fold cross validation. I have 93 features of 1000 users. What is the value of n accrording to my scenario?

Comment: 1000 users means 1000 rows in your dataset ,ryt ? Then n is 1000. 
BTW,it's not some hard and fast rule for k . U should try what I have mentioned in the answer ,starting with the value sqrt(n) and change the value accordingly.

Comment: isn't n = number of data points in the training data? If it's the case isn't n=900 (because I use 10 fold cross validation)

Comment: Yeah u r ryt,I missed the cross-validation part.

Comment: thank you :) btw one more question. In my problem I have 2 classes. I heard that in 2 class problems k values should be an odd number. so when taking the square root of 900 it is 30 (which is an even number). What will be the solution for this. should I use 29 or 31? :)

Answer (score 1):

The best K is the one that gives you the best performance given the dataset and how it generalizes to the unseen data.

The way K-NN works is that it builds a graph between your samples based on feature similarity between them. Each sample is connected to the K most similar samples. For prediction given the K neighbours of a sample, a label that has the majority vote among the K neighbours and so is most common in the neighbourhood is chosen as the predicted label.

K should definitely be lower than (#samples - 1) because in that case, all the samples are connected and then the label with the highest training samples will be predicted for all unlabelled samples.

If k equals 1, we are saying that the label of an unlabelled sample (test/unseen sample) should be equal to the label of the most similar sample to it.

You should choose a very low K (say 1) if you are very sure about your features and you know that the most similar training sample is good enough  for prediction.

You should choose a high K if you're not sure about your features and you want more samples to vote for it.

It is like if you like few expert people to vote for something or all people vote for something.

How to choose a proper K for your problem?
You should put away part of your data for development set. Loop over different values of K (e.g. from 1 to #samples-1) and see which one gives you the best result.

However, the rule of thumb is that if the number of samples is high enough (e.g. 10X the number of features), then the square root of the number of features should be a good initial guess but you need to loop over different values of K and see which one is the best for you.

To check the result you need to know the label of a number of samples but assume that you don't have that. You try to predict a label for those samples by looping over different values of K. You compare the predicted labels to the known labels and measure the accuracy (or F measure) and you choose the best K that gives you the best performance (e.g. highest F measure).

Remember to scale your feature values so that all of them are between 0 and 1 (normalization).

and also check the performance with and without every each of the features to see which features are actually helping in the prediction task.

I'd recommend using scikit-learn's k nearest neighbour implementation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier)

Comment: As in your answer the best k value to start with is the square root of number of features or number of points in the training data set? :) I have 93 features of 1000 users. Can you tell me what value I should consider to obtain the square root :)

Comment: PS: I use 10 fold cross validation

Comment: I'd say try 2^0, 2^1, 2^2, 2^3, 2^4, 2^5 and 2^6 and check each of performances then choose the best performing one. They say use an odd number for K so that for each neighbourhood you can have a majority vote. If your graph is not binary (edge weights are not 0 and 1 which happens when you use Cosine similarity of sample features) then you don't need to choose an odd number of neighbours.

Answer (score 0):

There are no pre-defined statistical methods to find the most favourable value of K. Choosing a very small value of K leads to unstable decision boundaries. Value of K can be selected as k = sqrt(n). where n = number of data points in training data Odd number is preferred as K value.

Most of the time below approach is followed in industry. Initialize a random K value and start computing. Derive a plot between error rate and K denoting values in a defined range. Then choose the K value as having a minimum error rate. Derive a plot between accuracy and K denoting values in a defined range. Then choose the K value as having a maximum accuracy. Try to find a trade off value of K between error curve and accuracy curve.